# Python - pdfme - writing utf-8 characters to file

Tags: python

I would like to generate report to pdf using pdfme library. I need the Polish characters to be there as well. The example report end with:

```py
with open('document.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    build_pdf(document, f)
```

So I cannot add encoding = "utf-8". Is there any way I can still use Polish characters?

I tried:

1. Change to write mode and set encoding to utf-8. Getting: *"TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes"*.
2. While having Polish characters add .encode("utf-8"). Example: `"Paweł".encode("utf-8")`. Getting: *"TypeError: value of . attr must be of type str, list or tuple: b'Pawe\xc5\x82'"*

Comment: Could you share the code that is defining `document` and the code for `build_pdf()`?  The code to be fixed will be in one or both of those areas.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the part of the code responsible for dealing with the unicode characters is the PDF library. The `build_pdf` call there, for whatever library it is,  has to be able to handle any character in "document". And if it fails it is the context for the PDF library, owner of the "build_pdf" call that has to be changed so that it will handle all the characters you need.

"utf-8" is just one form os expressing characters as bytes - aPDF file is a binary file, and it does have internal headers, structures and settings to do its own character encoding handling: your text may endup inside the PDF either encoded as utf-8, or some other, legacy encoding- but that will be transparent for you and anyone using the PDF file.

It *may be* that the `document`, if it is text (we don't know if it is plain text, or if it is some object from your library that has already been pre-processed) - but *if* it is text, and your library says that `build_pdf` can accept bytes instead, you can encode the document prior to this call:

`build_pdf(document.encode('utf-8', f)`  - but that would be some strange way of working - it is likely that either `build_pdf` will do the encoding, or whatever process generated the `document` had already done so.

To get more meaningful help, you have to say which library you are using to geneate the PDF, and include the `import` lines in your code,including the creation of your `document` so that we have a minimal reproducible example: i.e. I can copy your code, paste in a `.py` file here, install the lib, run it, and see a corrupted PDF file with the Polish characters magled: then I, and others, can be able to fix it. Otherwise, this answer is as far as I can get.